# Assign the result of current_setting('the_setting') to a variable in PL/pgSQL

Tags: postgresql, plpgsql, parameter

I have a function where I need to get a configuration parameter and assign it to a variable that I will use later in the function. The problem is that when the configuration parameter is not recognized (because it does not exist yet) the function dies. I want to evaluate if the variable was able to be assigned and if not set a null value to it.

This is what I tried:

```
   DECLARE
      conf_param text;
      num integer;

   BEGIN
      SELECT current_setting('the_setting') INTO conf_param;
         -- here is where dies when the_setting is not recognized!
      IF FOUND THEN
         num := conf_param::integer;
      ELSE
         num := NULL;
      END IF;
      -- more stuff
```

I am not sure if I am using `Found` the way is needed.

Comment: If you are using Postgres 9.6 you can simplify that to `conf_param := current_setting('the_setting', true);` In version before that you need to catch the exception

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had to surround that line in a block and catch the exception:

```
DECLARE
   num integer;

BEGIN
   BEGIN
      num := current_setting('the_setting')::integer;
   EXCEPTION
      WHEN SQLSTATE '42704' THEN
         num := NULL;
   END;
   --more stuff
```

Answer (score 5):

In Postgres **9.6** or later you can have this much simpler. Like [a_horse commented](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/165361/evaluating-select-current-settingthe-setting-into-a-variable-in-pl-gsql-func#comment319081_165361), there is a new variant of [`current_setting()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-admin.html#FUNCTIONS-ADMIN-SET-TABLE) that takes a second parameter `missing_ok`, to suppress exceptions if the configuration parameter (poor man's "global variable") is not set. So no expensive error trapping required any more.

And you don't need another variable `conf_param`, you can cast the result of the function call directly:

```
DECLARE
   num integer;
BEGIN
   num := current_setting('the_setting', true)::int;
   -- more stuff
END;
```

This is assuming the config parameter is *always* a valid `numeric` string if set. If you are not completely sure about that, you can either add an `EXCEPTION` clause to trap possible casting errors after all. Or test the value before casting to rule out exceptions. Typically much cheaper. Detailed instructions:

- [Filter strings with regex before casting to numeric](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42216764/939860)

Comment: @RomanTkachuk: True, if we are not sure that the parameter is always valid `numeric`if set. The OP's code has no provision for this, either. Assigning to a text variable and *then* casting does not buy anything here. I added some pointers to address the potential problem.