# How to implement "SELECT INTO" in Oracle with PostgreSQL commands?

Tags: postgresql, oracle, plsql, plpgsql, select-into

I have seen many explanations about `SELECT INTO` in the oracle clause. I found a difference in applying `SELECT INTO` in Oracle and other SQL databases. In Oracle, the `SELECT INTO` statement retrieves values from one or more database tables (as the SQL `SELECT` statement does) and stores them in variables (which the SQL `SELECT` statement does not do). Whereas in Postgres, `SELECT INTO` creates a new table from the results of a query.

I want to apply/implement such a thing in Postgres. What is the appropriate command or statement there?

Here is my Oracle query:

```
SELECT COUNT(1)
INTO ada
FROM atk_history_qty
WHERE tgl BETWEEN TO_DATE ('2014/02/01', 'yyyy/mm/dd')
AND TO_DATE ('2014/02/28', 'yyyy/mm/dd');
```

Comment: Select INTO is not "SQL" it's **PL/SQL** and PostgreSQL's PL/pgSQL supports the same thing. So if you are converting a stored procedure or function from PL/SQL to PL/pgSQL, this should be pretty much the same syntax. Btw: it's an urban myth that `count(1)` is faster than `count(*)`. In fact in Postgres `count(1)` is actually slightly slower.

Comment: `count(1)` is fractionally slower in Oracle as well, as the parser has to convert it into `count(*)` and that has to take a couple of cpu cycles.

Answer (score 1):

There are no variables in PostgreSQL's SQL dialect (nor are there in the SQL standard). If you are using `psql` as a client, you can use `psql` variables with `\gset`:

```
test=> SELECT count(*) AS myvar FROM pg_class \gset
test=> \echo :myvar
580
```

`\gset` creates variables with the same name as the aliases in the `SELECT` list.

Answer (score 0):

[**"Customized options"**](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/runtime-config-custom.html) have been extended to be usable for this purpose:

```
SELECT set_config('myvar.ada', count(*)::text, false)
FROM   atk_history_qty
WHERE  tgl BETWEEN date '2014-02-01' AND date '2014-02-28';
```

Then:

```
SELECT current_setting('myvar.ada')::bigint;
```

[The manual:](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-admin.html#FUNCTIONS-ADMIN-SET-TABLE)

> `set_config` ( `setting_name` `text`, `new_value` `text`, `is_local`
> `boolean` ) → `text`
>
> Sets the parameter `setting_name` to `new_value`, and returns that
> value. If `is_local` is `true`, the new value will only apply during
> the current transaction. If you want the new value to apply for the
> rest of the current session, use `false` instead. This function
> corresponds to the SQL command [`SET`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-set.html).

There are some limitations:

- Only strings (type `text`) are stored and retrieved. You may have to cast the type back and forth. (Like demonstrated in the example.)
- To set user-options apart from system parameters, the name must be qualified with an extension name, like `myvar.ada`.

Asides:

`count(*)` is always preferable to `count(1)`. It's equivalent, but a bit faster.
Dates in ISO format are always unambiguous, so we don't need `to_date()` for this input. If `tgl` is type `date`, the plain literal `'2014-02-01'` does it, too.

There are various other options to store variables, depending on context and scope:

- [Is there a way to define a named constant in a PostgreSQL query?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13317628/939860)
- [Store query result in a variable using in PL/pgSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12328198/939860)
- [Declaring variable for a whole script](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/213919/declaring-variable-for-a-whole-script/213921#213921)